# Make placeholder text inside html text field blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

Before asking this question I searched a lot for this functionality but did'nt find any clue so that's why posting a new question.

So actually I have a placeholder text inside an html text field like this

[image: A input field with placeholder text]

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Placeholder Text..." >
```

So what I want is to make this placeholder blink. So is it possible in html or by using jquery or javascript.

Comment: How about using css animations?

Comment: this is a jQuery kind of workaround that should work on all OS/browsers which support placeholder attribute but this is really a 'poor' solution compares too @dr_dev's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/jda339up/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jQuery-only way to do this:

```js
function blinker() {

  if ($('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder')) {
    // get the placeholder text
    $('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder', '');
  } else {
    $('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder', 'Placeholder Text...');
  }

  setTimeout(blinker, 1000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="blinker()">
  <input type="text" onclick="blinker()" class="timepicker" placeholder="Placeholder Text...">
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with simple CSS animations. Not sure, how much cross-browser compatible this is though. Works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here" class="textbox">
```

CSS:

```
input[class="textbox"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:blue;
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

input[class="textbox"]::-moz-placeholder { 
    color:blue;
    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}

@-moz-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkwa19se/6/

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal this works on chrome 39.0.2171.95 but looks like issue regarding page needing a refresh, not sure why?!

Comment: It works on both Chrome 39.0.2171, as well as Firefox 34.0.5. I have checked it. Refer to the updated section.

Comment: @dr_dev doesn't work for me on first page load (chrome win7). Once page refresh, works as expected. EDIT: if CSS rules are set after input element, works on first page load

Comment: @dr_dev wait will check